# Secure Port with Nginx Web Server Authentication auth_basic

Tags: nginx, http-basic-authentication

I am trying to secure the login URL of my website (Ajenti control panel) with auth_basic authentication. I access the site like this: **https://myajentiinstallation.com:8787**

In the file **/etc/nginx.custom.d/codes.conf**, I have this code:

```
server {
        listen 8787 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/other/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/other/key.key;
        location / {
                auth_basic "Admin Login";
                auth_basic_user_file /etc/other/htpass;
        }
}
```

However, when I go to **https://myajentiinstallation.com:8787**, I am taken to Nginx's default page!

How can I secure my Ajenti login page with auth_basic authentication?

Thanks!

Comment: Either the config you posted is incomplete, or you are missing some kind of directive telling nginx what to do with incoming requests - for example `root` pointing to a static document root, or `proxy_pass` passing requests to a backend handler.

It might also be that you're missing a `server_name` directive setting the host name, so your requests are falling back to the default vhost.

Comment: Have you tested config and restarted nginx?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, yes, when I run `nginx t`, everything is OK. I have restarted Nginx and have even restarted the entire server, but it is still giving the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure your `myajentiinstallation.com` points to right server?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, yes. Without the above directives, I am able to access the website just fine. It is just when I try to secure it with auth_basic with the above directives, that it brings me to Nginx's default page.